# Designing web service calls that read/write from database

Tags: database, web-services, asmx

Apologies for the newbie web service question -

I am trying to create a webservice that has a list of methods to perform read/writes to a database. An example function will be of form  -

```
CreateNewEmployee(string username, string employeeid, string deptname)
```

I created a webservice in .net (asmx) that has the above mentioned webmethod. In that, I open the connection to the data base and do an insert in to the database and then close the connections. Is this the right way to design the web service call?

Should I instead be passing an object instead of multiple parameters?

Any pointers toward best practices when trying to create a webservice that writes data into a database?

To add some more information

- We would like to have web services since it might be reused by many different applications within the organization (both web and desktop).
  We are also planning to create an environment where users can use these web services to create data mashups.

Thanks, 
Nate

Comment: Note that you should not be using ASMX web services unless you have no choice. They  have been replaced by WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - pass objects vs large parameter sets.  Also, have you considered WCF if you're in a .Net environment?  If you look at how ADO.Net Data Services (formerly Astoria) works, it will put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Will look into WCF.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from the winning answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204653/when-should-a-web-service-not-be-used):

> **Web Services are an absolutely horrible choice for data access.**
> It's a ton of overhead and complexity for almost zero benefit.

You can read the rest of the discussion there.

**Edit**: One excellent approach to having a common data access functionality that can be shared by multiple applications - web, desktop, service - is to **create a Visual Studio project that compiles to a DLL**. Each solution that wants to use the data access functionality references the DLL, which can deployed to the GAC or some other central location, or just added to the project's bin folder. Alternately, in order to be able to step through the data access code, the data access project can be added to a solution.

This is a very common practice in large enterprises, where many back office applications share common functionality. It is used not just for data access, but also for other services such as logging and authentication/authorization. Some divisions create a set of these DLLs, which they refer to as their "framework". It ensures that every application will have the same functionality and the same business logic, and that there is a single place for revisions to be made that will affect all of the applications. This is a similar benefit to using web services, but it avoids the overhead and performance hit of web services.

Comment: Edited the post to add more information. We will have quite a bunch of users trying to re-use the services as well. Any suggestions?