# Issues while working with Simplemembership

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, simplemembership

I am trying to implement Simple membership in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application targeting .NET Framework 4.0.
I have referred many articles, but all showing it targeted for .NET Framework 4.5.
Finally, I selected following article to implement this in my MVC application
[Decoupling Simplemembership from MVC application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.in/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-yol)
The only difference is that -

1. I have .NET Framework 4.0 rather than 4.5
2. I am consuming the SimpleMembership from WCF service rather than
   MVC.

I am getting following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Custom_SimpleMembership' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Following is what I have in WCF's config

```
<context type="SimpleSecurity.Repositories.SecurityContext,
Custom_SimpleMembership" disableDatabaseInitialization="false">
<databaseInitializer
type="SimpleSecurity.DropCreateSecurityDb, Custom_SimpleMembership" />
</context>
```

The assembly where I have implemented simplemembership is named as "Custom_SimpleMembership", and I have referenced it in my WCF project. Also the namespaces are correct (i.e. SimpleSecurity)

Comment: Is there an assembly in the bin directory named Custom_SimpleMembership.dll?  I would not put your memembership provider in a web service for performance and security reasons.  Are you are doing it just because of the .NET 4.0 constraints?

Comment: I have placed membership provider in a web service because I do not want my MVC application to directly access database.

Comment: You forgot to answer my first question about whether you can see the assembly in the bin directory for your web service. I do not know all of your project requirements but look at this QA [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204653/when-should-a-web-service-not-be-used].  Web services are not always the answer.