# use java and .net in same project

Tags: java, asp.net

I am trying to develop a small project in college. My team mates want to go for **Java** technology while I am more interested in **.net**.

Is it possible to develop the web site using Java and then redirecting it to .net(asp.net,which is our final module)?

So that I can work on .net module while letting my friends work on Java. Summing it up, Is it possible to develop the project(web site) using java and .net both(in the same project)? I googled it but didnt found anything relevant.

can you please help.

Comment: The short answer is No - you cannot create one application using two completely separate technologies.

Comment: Stop being difficult and go with your team mates, it seems like they hold the majority. It's just a school project. And if you're in college, for all intents and purposes Mike's "short answer" holds – unless expressly required to, trying to get a polyglot architecture set up in a single app is extra work you don't need to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Develop your website using HTML and JavaScript, may be you can use libraries like jQuery etc. For Back end develop web services. Because Web Services could be implemented in any language. You can change the underlaying language without breaking the website.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a split in deciding technologies, you can break the project into modules. Now you can find a few modules which can be exposed as web services. So you can create webservices in whichever language you wish. This way you get to learn both the technologies and also get to learn more about webservices.

Few Useful links

1. [Calling .net webservice from JAVA](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx)
2. [Webservices: Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp)
3. [When not to use webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204653/when-should-a-web-service-not-be-used)

IMHO just because as a team you cannot decide which technology to use, you should not jump into using webservices. They should only be used after proper evaluation and analysis. You might end up putting lot more effort than you planned.